# Can the vega of ITM call-options be negative when the distribution of the underlyings returns is negatively skewed?

Tags: european-options, vega, variance-gamma

While calculating european call option prices, using the variance-gamma model formula provided by Madan, Carr & Chang (1998), I noticed that, holding all other things constant, the value of an ITM call option in the VG-model seems to decline with $\sigma$ when the skewness parameter $\theta < 0$.

Below is depicted, for ATM, ITM and OTM-options respectively, the call price reduced by the mean price of its category (by parameters and moneyness category) versus $\sigma$. My concern regards figures 2 and 5.

I understand the argument, as is also presented in answers to many other questions about the vega of ITM-options, that due to the limited downside of call-options, an increase in volatility will also mean a higher expected payoff and therefore value.

**My question is, whether this is also true for ITM options when the underlying distribution of returns is negatively skewed?**

It is possible that the reason for this pattern in the figures is incorrect calculations on my behalf.

The option prices are for $S_0 =1000$, $r_f = 0.002$, $(T-t)=0.3$,

$K_{ATM}=1000$, $K_{ITM}=900$ and $K_{OTM}=1100$, and the VG-parameters shown in the graphs.

(The titles of the figures use "," instead of "." as decimal points)

[image]